# Refreshing site in react.js not working with query parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, koa, react-router

I have problem when I hit F5 in the browser.

I have route defined in react-router:

`<Route name="realestatesPrefiltered" path="realestatesPrefiltered/:search/:type" handler={RealEstatesPage}/>`

and route on node.js

`app.use(route.get("/realestatesPrefiltered/:search/:type", getLayout));`

but when I hit F5 i see blank page, why ?

I have another route without parameters.

`<Route name="realestates" handler={RealEstatesPage}/>`

`app.use(route.get("/realestates", getLayout));`
and everything is working ok.

Comment: Those are not query params, those are params constructed from the url.

Comment: OK, thanks but problem is not solved.

Comment: pls post all your react-router configuration